# How can I set a panic in anchor?

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, anchor-lang

How can I modify this [Anchor tutorial code](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/examples/tutorial/basic-2/programs/basic-2/src/lib.rs)
in a way so when any non-authority wallet tries to update the `count` variable it will give a message with an error like `only owner can modify the value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to create an error, the message will be sent when the error is thrown

```
#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("This is an ERROR!")]
    MyCustomError,
}
```

then in your instruction

```
if something_is_wrong {
    return Err(error!(ErrorCode::DrawAlreadyOffered));
}
```

Comment: That's another question that needs to have a seperate post. Please open another post, thank you :))